# setting the tomcat context path

Tags: java, tomcat, alfresco

I am running alfresco (alfresco.war) on tomcat server..

Presently i am using the url as http://kmkhub/alfresco .. it is redirecting into the alfresco website..

But i want to type kmkhub in the browser.. it will redirect into the .. alfresco website..

Can you provide the suggestions.. how can i achieve it..

Regards,
krishna

Answer (score 2):

goto war check `web.xml` contextroot make it blank instead of `alfresco` 
or goto tomcat admin console and deploy and specify context path blank from UI 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to name your war `ROOT.war`  and deploy it (remove/rename) the ROOT folder before that

Another option is to an `.xml` context configuration file with `<Context path="/" />`:

> In individual files (with a ".xml" extension) in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ directory. The name of the file (less the .xml extension) will be used as the context path. Multi-level context paths may be defined using #, e.g. foo#bar.xml for a context path of /foo/bar. The default web application may be defined by using a file called ROOT.xml.

You can also have this in `META-INF/context.xml` in the WAR.

[See here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the URL displayed in the browser the easiest way is to create a redirect in the ROOT webapp.

Create this index.jsp file in the ROOT webapp:

```
<%
response.sendRedirect("/alfresco");
%>
```

Changing the name of the alfresco app, as proposed by the others, will work but you would need to alter the configuration for the share webapp as well because Share connects to http://localhost/alfresco. To change the URLs you would have to edit the configuration files found in `tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\web-extension`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven + Tomcat7 Maven Plugin, then just configure your Root Path as shown below:

[image]

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <path>/</path>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```